# do you need a constructor method in es6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

if I don't include a constructor method inside a class definition, is it implicitly created? Do I need to include one in es6?
ex:

```js
class Rectangle {
  // no constructor method defined

  // function
  draw() {
    some code
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know any language where constructors are **required** in classes. It's only there if you need to do things when creating an instance of a class, like set values or fire off side effects

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/class "The constructor method is optional."